# How to import accounts with mnemonic in web3 console

Tags: go-ethereum

```
geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

How to import accounts with mnemonic in this Geth console...
like `web3.personal.importRawKey("XXXX")`

Comment: Geth's console uses web3 v0.20 that version doesn't support creating a wallet from a seed phrase.

Comment: finaly I use some js code to convert mnemonic to private key batchly, then import